# How do you uninstall an app when tap uninstall is missing?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

How do I remove unwanted items from the app list? I can't use metro tiles, so I rely on the app list as a way of navigating my phone. I want to remove items like 'Xbox' which make absolutely no sense being there. Thanks.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use live tiles?

Answer (score 5):

If the uninstall option is missing when long-pressing on an app, it means it's a built-in app and cannot be uninstalled. You'll just have to live with it, I'm afraid.